# Using jquery for numerical validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, math, percentage

I am trying to create something with javascript/jquery.

Every time I click on the fake Validate "button", I am trying to get the final value to subtract a number. In this case, I chose the number 1. Also, can I use a percentage symbol with the number?

Basically, in the form there will be a number typed in by someone.
Then, once they click on "validate", the final total will subtract THAT number from it.

There is already a set of radio buttons that determines what the number will be in the total at the very end.

```
<form action="example.php" onsubmit="validateForm()">    
    <a id="a_is_valid" href="#">Validate</a>
    <input type="text" id="code_promo" name="code_promo" value="" />
    <input type="text" name="gtotal" id="gtotal" class='fTotal' value=""  />    
</form>
```

Yes, there is a button later on in the code to submit it - so I am not concerned whatsoever about submitting it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var new_total = $('#gtotal').val();
    $('#a_is_valid').click(function () {
        if ($('#code_promo').val() == 55) {
            new_total - 1
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: so what is the question here?

Comment: should it not be `new_total -= 1` or something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what i understood, I am guessing, you want to reduce the value based on the code promo.
Here is how you would set the total:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#a_is_valid').click(function () {
        if ($('#code_promo').val() == 55) {
            $('#gtotal').val($('#gtotal').val()-1);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes, precisely!

Thank you for making me understand what was my error, karthikr. I will study the code in depth to make sure I fully understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe next functions can help you: [`parseInt()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) or [`parseFloat()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp). After, you can compare with strict mode `number === 1`.

Comment: Yes, that will help for the total (although the actual total has that function already).